# Charged capacitor as output

Tags: inverter, charging, charge, electrolytic-capacitor

Ok this is a two part question, it's so that I can make the question as clear as possible.

Let's say I have 1 watt of input power into a circuit or device and 1 joule of energy sitting in a capacitor as output, for example 100V at 200uF.

Is a capacitor just sitting there and being continuously charged with a constant 1 joule of energy considered as an output?

Also I understand that a joule is equal to one watt second. So if I am observing a continuous 1 watt of input power of 1 watt but I only observe it for just one second, would it be correct or incorrect to say that the output of 1 joule charged in a capacitor is equal to the input power of 1 watt?

The circuit I am speaking of is a basic DC to DC inverter type or buck booster with flyback and the flyback is charging the capacitor.

I understand that during the charging of the capacitor let's say from a 0 voltage the input source will experience a loading and draw lots of current at first in order to begin charging the capacitor.

Afterwards when the the capacitor is fully charged and the input current has settled down into a stabilized power in which a meter can read is the point in which I am referring to.

So in a nutshell, the main question again is, is the one watt second in the input equal to the 1 joule in the capacitor, which is considered a one watt second, all within the same second? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused between energy and power, which is the rate of energy transfer. If no current is going into or out of the capacitor, the energy it stores is not changing (\$E = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{Q^2}{C}\$, and \$Q\$ isn't changing). The power you describe that is being input into the circuit must therefore be dissipated somewhere else in the circuit, for example by heating up a resistor.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even think about that, now I just feel completely stupid, or maybe I don't even know what I am asking. I think what I am trying to ask is how to figure out input and output power in the charging of a capacitor with a DC to DC converter.

Comment: So the circuit's just a power source connected to a capacitor?

Comment: The circuit is a DC to DC inverter or converter, basic, more like a joule thief, it's charging a capacitor. Those figures are just examples. I understand what the charge is that gets into the cap, but I don't know how to compare it to the input power, I don't have an O-Scope, so I was just trying to figure that out or find out of there was an easier way of seeing this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Probably best to ask another, clearer and more concise question.